# Como obter somente uma coluna de uma query em Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
   $uf      = $request->uf; 
   $valor   = $request->valor; 

   $cotacao = Cotacao::where('uf','like', '%'.$uf.'%')->get();
   if($cotacao != '') {
      return response()->json($cotacao);
   }
}
```

Meu resultado é esse:

```js
[
   {
      "id":2,
      "uf":"PA",
      "percentual_cotacao":"2.10",
      "valor_extra":"1.20",
      "transportadora_id":2,
      "created_at":"2022-06-28T23:20:18.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2022-06-28T23:20:18.000000Z"
   }
]
```

Preciso somente do campo `uf`

Comment: Ué, mas a ideia desse seu filtro já não é trazer somente itens de uma determinada UF? Estranho retornar só UF nos dados, já que todos os itens seriam da mesma UF, que você já sabe qual é de antemão...

Comment: Dei uma melhorada na sua pergunta para ela parecer um pouco mais canônica para futuros visitantes entender melhor o escopo da sua pergunta e da minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode passar um array com as colunas que quer obter na query no método `get()`:

```php
$cotacao = Cotacao::where('uf','like', '%'.$uf.'%')->get(['uf']);
// somente $cotacao->uf estará disponível
```

Também pode usar o `select`:

```php
$cotacao = Cotacao::select('uf')->where('uf','like', '%'.$uf.'%')->get();
// somente $cotacao->uf estará disponível
```

Ou o `pluck`:

```php
$cotacao = Cotacao::where('uf','like', '%'.$uf.'%')->pluck('uf')->get();
```

Se preferir da maneira tradicional do PHP, pode usar `array_intersect` quando você obtém um array da query. Essa forma é mais lenta porque irá obter todos as colunas de um registro, até as que você não vai usar.

```php
// usando o first(), que pega somente o primeiro registro
// da consulta

$cotacao = Cotacao::where('uf','like', '%'.$uf.'%')->first()->toArray();
$cotacao = array_intersect($cotacao, ['uf']);
// somente $cotacao['uf'] estará disponível

// usando o get() que obtém uma coleção de registros
// da consulta
$cotacao = Cotacao::where('uf','like', '%'.$uf.'%')->get()->toArray();
$cotacao = array_intersect($cotacao[0], ['uf']);
// somente $cotacao['uf'] estará disponível
```

Claro que se estiver trabalhando com vários itens de coleção a primeira opção dessa resposta é a mais viável, ou se quiser utilizar o `->get()->toArray()`, terá que fazer um `array_map` para preparar os itens com o `array_intersect`.

Note que `array_intersect` só funciona com arrays e não objetos. Se a consulta retornar um objeto ao invés de um array, o código não funcionará.

Comment: usei o first e deu certo. origado